# How to disable and enable Spinner items on user click

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am developing an android app, which asks security questions after Sign Up for forgot password purpose, which has 10 questions in total. User can select any 3.
I have 3 Spinner for 3 question. Once user select the question from first spinner, second and third spinner should not have them in their list. Please help me to disable or remove that from the list.

screen shot of the activity

[image]

Comment: on each new security question selected just remove the item from the adapter you might want to do this with an interface, adapter to activity/fragment the call notifydatasetchanged so the item gets removed from the list.  Just make sure before removal to call for a refresh from the webservice as to handle scenario when user changes security question.

Comment: @Ramu Hegde Check my answer, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set a boolean check if it is the first time a spinner is selected. Store the selected item, so that you can add them on question change later.

```
Boolean ifFirstCheck = true;
String storeItem = "";
```

Then, Use below code:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                   if(!ifFirstCheck){
                       listSp2.add(storeItem);
                       sp2adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
                       listSp3.add(storeItem);
                       sp3adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
                   }

                   String selectedItem = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                   listSp2.remove(selectedItem)             // Get selected value from spinner1 and remove thar item from spinner2
                   sp2adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();      // Notify adapter of spinner2 to that dataset has been changed
                   listSp3.remove(selectedItem)
                   sp3adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                   storeItem = selectedItem;
                   ifFirstCheck = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Do as above for rest of the spinners.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using an Adapter for the Spinners. If you use an ArrayAdapter and each adapter holds the same list of items, you can just remove the selected items from the list and notify the adapters to update.

Comment: but if user changes question from the first spinner than that question must be added to the list again.

Comment: if he refreshes content by calling webservice with container information before removal then it will handle the security question changes.